# Is there any way to dredge a PGLMM_compare model in R (Phyr and MuMin packages)?

Tags: r, phylogeny, mumin

I am doing a comparative analysis, and my response variables are 0 or 1, therefore I need to do a phylogenetically-corrected analysis with a binomial error distribution. I used the PGLMM_compare function from the phyr package (https://rdrr.io/github/daijiang/phyr/man/pglmm_compare.html) to create a full model with all of my variables, but MuMin does not support this output as a 'global model', therefore I cannot dredge it. I am looking for a way to find the best models and possibly perform model averaging from these, however it seems that these packages are not compatible. It would be difficult to create all the models by hand, since I have ~8 explanatory variables. Is there any way of dredging a phylogenetic model with binomial error structure? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to implement at least the following methods for `dredge` and `model.avg` to work with `pglmm_compare`:

```r
nobs.pglmm_compare(object, ...) 
logLik.pglmm_compare(object, ...)
coef.pglmm_compare(object, ...) 
coefTable.pglmm_compare(model, ...)
```